# How to revoke a Trello access token from an application?

Tags: trello

If a user has provided a token to an application so it can access their private data, how does the user then revoke access before the token expires? I don't see it anywhere in the user settings, but maybe I'm just blind.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to view (and revoke) your tokens at https://trello.com/my/account

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but it says that no applications are using my account.